# Адаптивный дизайн: технологии

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Скажите пожалуйста, является ли использование `flex` заменой вёрстке при помощи `float`? или нужно юзать и то и другое? и стоит ли изучать и использовать `grid layout` или css фреймворки типа Skeleton? в общем, какие есть плюсы и минусы каждого из подходов и все ли они поддерживаются браузерами в допустимом виде (в частности Safari)?

Comment: На заголовок ответ `css @media`, `flex` наверное да, хорошая замена но с багами в ие. Сетку скорее не изучать надо а понять, дальше либо сами сетку сделаете как удобно, либо чужую использовать. А что с `Safari` не так? Он вообще впереди планеты всей. Первые v8 засунули, год уже как css3 backdrop-filter работает итд

Answer (score 0):

float знать нужно, но да flexbox эффективнее, а у grid layout поддержка пока очень плоха. К слову, Bootstrap 4 использует технологию flex. Если хотите быть нормальным специалистом, то нужно уметь вёрстку без фреймворков.

Comment: Нормальному специалисту хватит табличной вёрстки.

Comment: И 640 килобайт ОЗУ хватит всем